# Is Java Control Panel still available in OpenJDK?

Tags: windows-10, openjdk

My team has upgraded from JDK 8 to JDK 11. Previously we configure web proxy settings in Java Control Panel (`javacpl.exe`); now we can't find this utility in JDK 11. We don't have `jre` folder in the JDK 11 folder. Is it still available (maybe with a new name), or is it excluded in OpenJDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this in another group ( https://github.com/corretto/corretto-8/issues/133 )

> Java Control Panel is a commercial feature in Java Deployment Technologies. It is not implemented in OpenJDK8 (and further versions). Feel free to reopen the issue if you have any further questions.